# why constant derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Really simple question here.

Consider two functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$. Then, why if$$\frac{d f(x)}{dx} = \frac{d g(y)}{dy} ,$$then both derivatives are constant?

Thank you all very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $ \dfrac{d g(y)}{dy} $ does not depend on $ x $ because it is the partial derivative of a function $g$ with respect to $y$. $x$ is not allowed to vary in this expression. Thus, $ \dfrac{d f(x)}{dx} $ does not depend on $ x $, because the other expression does not depend on $ x $.

As Damien L has said, the same is true for $ y $.

Comment: Thank you. I have now understood.

Answer (score 3):

Because $g$ is a *constant* function of $x$, so $\frac{df}{dx}$ is equal to a constant function of $x$.

Same for $f$ and $y$.